# Accessing related objects in Django

Tags: django

I have the below model

```
class Question(db.Model):
    userid = db.CharField(max_length=50)
    posted = db.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    question = db.TextField(max_length=500)
    qid = db.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = db.TextField(max_length=80)

class Question_tags(db.Model):
    tag = db.ForeignKey('Tags')
    ques = db.ForeignKey('Question')

class Tags(db.Model):
    tid = db.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    tagname = db.CharField(max_length=30)
    tag_cnt = db.IntegerField()
```

I need to join the 3 models namely Question, Tags and Question_tags and get the below fields question, title, tagname and tag_cnt. I tried with select_related(), but I am getting error like "queryset doesn't contain the object select_related"... Any idea on how to proceed??

Answer (score 2):

1. Instead a M2M table, you should use a `ManyToManyField`; this is quite the equivalent of what you did there with your `Question_tags`, but much more convenient.
2. I don't know exactly what query do you want (please post some code...), but here are some examples which may clarify what you need to know:

   ```
   Question.objects.get(pk=some_question_id).question_tags_set.all()
   # get all tags of a specific `Question`
   Tags.objects.get(tagname="some_tag").question_tags_set.all()
   # all questions of a specific `Tag`
   ```

**EDIT**:

To change your models for `ManyToManyField`, use this:

```
class Tags(db.Model):
    tid = db.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    tagname = db.CharField(max_length=30)
    tag_cnt = db.IntegerField()

class Question(db.Model):
    userid = db.CharField(max_length=50)
    posted = db.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    question = db.TextField(max_length=500)
    qid = db.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = db.TextField(max_length=80)
    tags = db.ManyToManyField(Tags)
```

And you can get the values like this:

```
Question.objects.get(pk=123).tags.all()
Tags.objects.get(tagname="mytag").question_set.all()

# to count tags for every Question
from django.db.models import Count
Question.objects.all().annotate(num_tags=Count("tags"))
```

Comment: Hi, I am not sure how to code this, but below is what I need to get.

For each question in Question, I need to get the relevant tagname from Tags. There could be more than one tag for a question. Question and Tags are linked only by Question_tags model. Moreover, I am not looking for a particular question, I need to get the tagname for all the objects(questions) in Question.

I am not sure, how to make it as M2M field instead of a M2M table. Can you please explain on how to do this. 

Thanks!!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. But, I want to know if something like this Question.objects.all().tags.all() is valid. If not, can you please advise on how to achieve this. I basically need a resultset with all the question objects along with their tagnames. Thanks!!

Comment: You cannot do that in django (at least as far as I know).. You would have to manually get tags for each question

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to access the `Question_tags` and `Tags` objects from an `Question` object, which would mean you follow the [foreign key relationship backwards](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).

```
question = Question.objects.get(pk=1)
question_tags = question.question_tags_set.all()
```

If you don't want to access the objects through `FOO_set`you can set a `related_name` on the field in the model:

```
class Question_tags(db.Model):
    tag = db.ForeignKey('Tags', related_name="my_tag_objects")
    ques = db.ForeignKey('Question')
```

Nevertheless if your models are like that I think your `Question_tags` model is redundant and can be replaced by a [`ManyToManyField`](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/many_to_many/) in `Question`.

Comment: Hi, can you please explain how to eliminate Question_tags by including a ManyToManyField in Question. Thanks!!